# Critical points of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Critical points of Z(x,y)=x^3+3xy^2-15x-12y
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGJOP.png)

I get confuse on how you get x^4-5x^2+4=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They only substituted $y=\frac{2}{x}$ in the equation above and then they multiplied it by $x^2$ to get better-looking equation so it can be solved better.